# mc:Repeatable background color mailchimp

Tags: html-email, mailchimp

I have repeatable sections in my html MailChimp template but cannot work out how to give the client the option to also change he background colour between white or green.

So far i have tried this

```
/*
@tab background-test
@section background-Colour
*/

    .background-test {
        /*@editable*/background-color:#000000 !important;
    }
```

And this in the body

```
<table width="650" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" class="wrapper" style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; table-layout:fixed;" mc:repeatable mc:variant="test color">
  <tr>
    <td align="center" valign="top" class="background-test">
      <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" mc:edit="change-background">
        <tr>
          <td width="30" class="hide"> </td>
          <td align="center" valign="top" class="pad_side">
            <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
              <tr>
                <td height="30" class="fix_height"> </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="white" align="center" valign="top" style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:24px;line-height:27px;color:#ffffff;" mc:edit="section2_maintitle">Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td height="7" style="line-height:1px;font-size:1px;"> </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="white" align="center" valign="top" style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;letter-spacing:1px;line-height:17px;color:#ffffff;" mc:edit="section2_semititle">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td height="30" class="fix_height"> </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </td>
          <td width="30" class="hide"> </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

But I want to be able to change the background colour per section, not all the repeated ones the same.

Also - is there a way to make it so they can only choose between 2 colours - in this case, either white or green (#82c9c2)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can you add an additional class? Like so:

```
/*
@tab background-test
@section background-Colour
*/

    .background-green {
        /*@editable*/background-color:green !important;
    }
    .background-white {
        /*@editable*/background-color:white !important;
    }
```

And in the body:

```
<table width="650" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" class="wrapper" style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; table-layout:fixed;" mc:repeatable mc:variant="test color">
  <tr>
    <td align="center" valign="top" class="background-green">
      <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" mc:edit="change-background">
        <tr>
          <td width="30" class="hide background-white"> </td>
          <td align="center" valign="top" class="pad_side">
            <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
              <tr>
                <td height="30" class="fix_height"> </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="white" align="center" valign="top" style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:24px;line-height:27px;color:#ffffff;" mc:edit="section2_maintitle">Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td height="7" style="line-height:1px;font-size:1px;"> </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="white" align="center" valign="top" style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;letter-spacing:1px;line-height:17px;color:#ffffff;" mc:edit="section2_semititle">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td height="30" class="fix_height"> </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </td>
          <td width="30" class="hide"> </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>

</table>
```